# React-Native Android : error on assembling in release mode

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, babeljs, eslint

My app runs fine when testing with `react-native run-android`, but when I try to build it in release mode (build the APK file), I have the following error.

The error :

```
uncaught error SyntaxError: unknown: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (30477:0)
  30475 | 
  30476 | 
> 30477 | export default conf;
        | ^
  30478 | });
  30479 | __d('qs/lib/utils.js',function(global, require, module, exports) {  var 
  30480 | 
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1921:16)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2294:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlock (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2275:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseFunctionBody (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1130:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseFunction (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2406:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseFunctionExpression (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:764:17)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:726:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/gregoirehamaide/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:509:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/<username>/Documents/<app>/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babylon/index.js:489:19)
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
```

I guess it comes from **Babel** or **Eslint** but I can't find out why.

Does someone know a way?

Thanks.

Comment: have you found any solution? I'm facing now the same problem ...